# Java Collection sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I am trying to sort a list of Dates and it's not working.

Here is the declaration and get function in AttEnt

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "end_time")
private Date endTime;

public Date getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}
```

Here is the sorting code that isn't doing anything. GetAttempts() gets the list of all the attempts for called.  They aren't in order, and I just want to be able to get whatever attempt has the latest endTime.

```
            List<AttEnt> attempts = called.getAttempts();
            Collections.sort(attempts, new Comparator<AttEnt>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(AttEnt a1, AttEnt a2) {
                if (a1.getEndTime() == null || a2.getEndTime() == null)
                    return 0;
                return a1.getEndTime().compareTo(a2.getEndTime());
                }
            });
```

I believe that the code above should sort attempts, and then after it attempts should be sorted, so the latest end time would be attempts.get(attempts.size()-1).getEndTime()

Comment: So if one of the objects is null, you say they are equal?

Comment: What is the output you get, and what is the output you want? Consider creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: By the way - `Comparator.comparing(AttEnt::getEndTime)` is I believe better than writing a custom comparator. It compares the values based on the natural ordering of the type extracted using the passed method reference.

Answer (score 1):

```
Comparator<AttEnt> comparator = Comparator.comparing(AttEnt::getEndTime).reversed();
attempts.sort(comparator);
```

Java static methods in interfaces are your friend

Click [HERE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for more awesomeness

Comment: Make sure your `AttEnt.getEndTime` does not return null

Comment: My bad `Comparator<AttEnt> comparator = Comparator.reverseOrder().thenComparing(AttEnt::getEndTime)`

Comment: How about this time `Comparator<AttEnt> comparator = Comparator.reverseOrder().thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(AttEnt::getEndTime))` Sorry, I haven't used the other methods for along time, so quite forget their API docs. But this time it should work

Comment: Still doesn't like that line.

Comment: I tried this also, and it doesn't work either Collections.sort(attempts, (a1, a2) -> a1.getEndTime().compareTo(a2.getEndTime()));